# Lisp - Check if input is Decimal or String

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am printing a triangle of numbers in Lisp and I want to make sure that the input upon calling the function is an integer. If it's a string or a decimal, it should return a message not accepting the input. This is my code for the numbers.

```
(defun nested-loop (n)
  (loop for i from 1 to n doing
  (loop for j from 1 to i collecting
    (progn
      (prin1 j)))
   (format t "~%")))

(nested-loop 5)
```

Comment: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_inte_1.htm#integerp

Comment: There are particular functions that allow you to see variable types. Look at Example 2 [on this website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lisp/lisp_data_types.htm)

Comment: @melpomene I used the integerp function but it replies "EVAL: undefined function INTERGERP"

Comment: @mendy Try `integerp` instead of `intergerp`.

Comment: oh boy, did not see that, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the macro `CHECK-TYPE`:

```
CL-USER 9 > (let ((n "10"))
              (check-type n integer))

Error: The value "10" of N is not of type INTEGER.
```